# How to find the difference of all consecutive sub-sequences?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I need to get an effective algorithm, which can find sum of the difference of all consecutive sub-sequences, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, all consecutive sub-sequences for 12345:

```
12    (Dif = 1)
23    (Dif = 1)
34    (Dif = 1)
45    (Dif = 1)
123   (Dif = 2)
234   (Dif = 2)
345   (Dif = 2)
1234  (Dif = 3)
2345  (Dif = 3)
12345 (Dif = 4)

Sum of the difference = 20
```

Count of sequence elements >= 2 <= 300000.

Each element >= 1 <= 10^7.

Time limit: 1s.

I wrote the code, but it's too slow:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.tie(0);
    iostream::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int count;
    cin >> count;

    int elem;

    vector<int> vec;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cin >> elem;

        if (vec.size() > 0) {
            sum += abs(vec.back() - elem);
        }

        vec.push_back(elem);
        if (vec.size() > 2) {
            sum += abs(*max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) -             *min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
        }

        for (int z = 3; z < count; z++) {
            if (vec.size() > z) {
                sum += abs(*max_element(vec.begin() + i - z + 1, vec.end()) - *min_element(vec.begin() + i - z + 1, vec.end()));
            }
        }
    }

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

I found that the count of sub-sequences can be found by the triangle numbers formula (Where is n - length of sequence):

```
count = 1/2 * n * (n - 1);
```

For n = 300000, count of sub-sequence is 45 billion.

How to do it faster? I need algorithm.

Comment: If you want improvement of already working code better ask over at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts were to build a tree in order to remember sub answers (i.e. dynamic-programming) and just combine the answers together.  However, each higher branch isn't strictly speaking the sum of the nodes below it.  Consider for example:
[image]

I noticed, however, that the nodes were predictable.  Namely:
[image]

And when expanded to 6 consecutive nodes:
[image]

Which, summarily expressed is

`SUM( i * (n - i) )`  with `i = [1 .. n)` where `n >=2`

This of course runs in O(N) time and doesn't require anything other than add + multiply.

---

However, it bothered me that perhaps this summation formula could be reduced to a simple equation.  So I looked up the [properties of summation formulas](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SummationNotation.aspx) and worked through to get a simple equation:

[image]

Which means that `(n^3 - n) / 6` should execute in O(1) time.  I tested it for the first 6 and it gave the right answers...